# Помогите склеить 2 запроса, если можно

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть рабочий запрос:

```
select p.*, pr.NUMBER_IN as NUMBER_IN_PR, c.EXECUTE_BEGIN as EXECUTE_BEGIN_C, c.EXECUTE_END as EXECUTE_END_C, c.CLIENT_ID as CLIENT_ID_C,
  c.PDV as PDV_C, c.PDV_WITHOUT as PDV_WITHOUT_C, c.PDV_TOTAL as PDV_TOTAL_C, c.FIRST_PART_NUMBER_CONTRACT as FIRST_PART_NUMBER_CONTRACT_C,
  c.CREATE_NUMBER as CREATE_NUMBER_C from PLAN_D p join CONTRACT c on p.CONTRACT_ID = c.ID join PROPOSAL pr on pr.ID = c.PROPOSAL_ID where c.SEND_STATUS = 1 and p.ARCHIVE = 1 order by p.ID
```

он выдает строки результата.
К каждой строке этого результата желательно прикрепить еще один запрос:

```
select distinct(sw.NAME_SORT_WORK) from DEVICES d
  join SORT_WORK sw on d.SORT_WORK_ID = sw.ID where d.PROPOSAL_ID = 1
```

результатом этого запроса, также могут стать несколько строк.
Мне нужно результат второго запроса превратить в строку (перечисление через запятую), и вставить в новое поле первого запроса. Ключевое поле объединения = "*PROPOSAL_ID*" (которое есть и в таблице "*CONTRACT*" и в таблице "*DEVICES*")

Заранее спасибо за ответ
P.S.
или тут без внутренней процедуры не обойтись?

Comment: Сделайте обычный join с этой таблицей. Добавьте gorup by по тем полям которые сейчас выводятся. А значения через запятую получайте `group_concat(distinct sw.NAME_SORT_WORK)`

Comment: извиняюсь (не правильно указал) я использую Firebird 3.0

Comment: разобрал, что второй запрос можно сделать так: "**select list(distinct(sw.NAME_SORT_WORK), ', ') from DEVICES d join SORT_WORK sw on d.SORT_WORK_ID = sw.ID where d.PROPOSAL_ID = 1**" и теперь его результат нужно объединить с результатом первого запроса по "*PROPOSAL_ID*"

Comment: Тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635451/firebird-2-5-equivalent-function-to-stuff-in-sql-group-concat-in-mysql-list вот пишут, что эквивалент group_concat для firebird функция list().